# ComboBox SelectionChanged event firing off unexpectedly

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, combobox

I have 4 ComboBoxes arranged horizontally :
The titles are just for reference.

**[Platforms] [Releases] [Release Items] [Release Item Products]**

My UI model for the boxes is as follows:

1. At first all four ComboBoxes are disabled (IsEnabled = false)
2. When the page loads, an async callback gets the Platforms data and binds it to the Platforms comboBox after Enabling it, and manually add "All" as an item.
3. User selects a platform

   If the user selects "All" , I do the following: Disable the other three comboboxes
   and call the Async method to rebind data to the platforms combo box.

   ```
           releasesFilterComboBox.IsEnabled = false;
           releaseItemsFilterComboBox.IsEnabled = false;
           releaseItemProductsFilterComboBox.IsEnabled = false;

           mainClient.GetBuildsAsync(null);
   ```

   If the user selects some other platform (other than 'All'), based on which platform is selected, I collect all the items that match the platform from the object in the DataContext, and set the ItemsSource of the Releases comboBox to it as follows:

> ```
> BuildsListBox.ItemsSource = platformSelectedBI = from bi in buildInfos where 
>                                                 bi.GetBuildsResult.ReleasePlatform ==  selectedPlatform
>                                                  select bi;
> releasesFilterComboBox.IsEnabled = true;
> ```

```
List<String> releaseNumbers = ( from bld in buildInfos.Where(bi => bi.GetBuildsResult.ReleasePlatform == selectedPlatform)
select bld.GetBuildsResult.ReleaseNumber ).ToList();

releaseNumbers.Insert(0, "All");
releasesFilterComboBox.ItemsSource = releaseNumbers.Distinct();
```

4. The rest of the ComboBoxes follow the exact same procedure to bind data, and trigger 
   and actions are performed in a method which is called when the SelectionChanged events are fired.

etc etc -> same for the rest of the boxes.

#### My Problem is: After I've populated at least the first two ComboBoxes, when I select

the 'All' option on a PREVIOUS ComboBox, after the expected behavior (other comboboxes are disabled), when I select an option other than 'ALL', the SelectionChanged event is triggered for EVERY COMBOBOX that was filled previously! (all that were disabled). ###

Just to clarify, if it isn't yet.

I've selected a Platform, and so Releases is populated. I've then selected a Release, and so Release Items is populated. Now, when I select 'ALL' on the Platforms combobox, the Release and Release Items boxes are disabled. Then, when I select a platform other than 'ALL',  the SelectionChanged event is fired, not just for Platforms, but also for Releases and ReleaseItems. 
The ONLY change I'm making to the comboboxes in the second part of the event handler is SETTING THE ITEMS SOURCE like the in code shown above. Nothing more.

Why are the SelectionChanged events being fired for the other comboBoxes?
Is this a known bug in SL comboboxes? Can I prevent this from happening?

I'm sorry if the question and explanation isn't very clear. I'll try my best to clarify if you ask me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Repopulating the list implies a selection change unless the selected item exists in the new list. And by exists I mean the same reference, not an 'Equal' one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all comes down to re-population of the lists.  One way you could fix it would be to remove the event handlers when you select "ALL" and disable the other combo boxes.  Then if you select something other than "ALL" you could set the datasources and then re-add the selection change event handler.

Another way would be to leave them all there and then in the "ALL" selection set the selected index to -1 (default) and in your event handler don't do anything if it's -1.

Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks Joshua I'm going to try both of these out!

Comment: I used the second method - changing the selected indices to -1 and handling them with just a return statement. It works! Thanks